# Find 1st or 2nd available (visible) select option using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have two HTML select boxes `#task` and `#sub-task`. When the user selects an option in `#task` it hides/shows the relevant options in `#sub-task`.

The first option in `#sub-task` is a "Please Select", so I would like to show the **2nd** available option after the user has select the `#task`.

This is my current JS:

```
$('#task').on('change', function () {
  $('#sub-task').show();
  $('#sub-task > option').hide();
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $('#sub-task option').each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.data('task-id') == selected) {
      el.show();
    }
  });

  // returns undefined
  console.log($('#sub-task').find("option:not(:hidden):eq(1)"));
});
```

I've tried the following to return the 2nd visible item I have tried the following:

```
$("#sub-task option:not(:hidden):eq(1)").val();
$("#sub-task option:visible:eq(1)").val();
```

If I remove the Please Select option and try to get the value of the first visible item, I've tried the following:

```
$("#sub-task option:visible:first").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select option base on first dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#first").change(change_fruit);
    $("#second").hide();
   
})

function change_fruit() {
    var selected=$("#first option:selected").text();
    var selectedFruit=$("#second").show();
    var options=$("#second option");
    options.hide();
    $.each(options,function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf(selected) > -1 ){
          $(this).show();
        }
        else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })
    //showing first option always
    $("#second option:eq(0)").show();
    //selecting first option in second dropdown.
     $("#second option:eq(1)").attr("selected",true);
    
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="first" id="first">
    <option value="0">-Select Fruit-</option>
    <option value="1" id="a">apple</option>
    <option value="4" id="b">banana</option>
    <option value="7" id="c">Clove</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second">
    <option value='0'>-Select Fruit-</option>"
    <option value="1" id="a">apple1</option>
    <option value="2" id="a">apple2</option>
    <option value="3" id="a">apple3</option>
    <option value="4" id="b">banana1</option>
    <option value="5" id="b">banana2</option>
    <option value="6" id="b">banana3</option>
    <option value="7" id="c">Clove1</option>
    <option value="8" id="c">Clove2</option>
    <option value="9" id="c">Clove3</option>
</select>
```